# Conjugation/grammar for fictitious title

Tags: grammar-choice, sentence-translation, conjugation, plural

In a work of fiction, I have an Order of ordained detectives that do not exist.  I use the term Lictor Rebus Sanctorae for the Order, and Lictor Rebus Sanctorus for the male protagonist.  I know this is very far off, and wish to get it right.  He is officially a Sami Cupien, a Liaison between the Vatican and international officials, but is in fact more of a secret agent-type.  I will appreciate any input, gratias tibi!

Comment: Welcome to the site! What do you intend the name to mean, exactly? Small differences can change the meaning a lot

Comment: I need the name of the order and his position to include the word rebus, which I have found means Operative. He's a liaison, but works in secret as an investigator. So "Order of Vatican Intelligence Operatives" and "Vatican Intelligence Operative" would be the terms I am looking for, and how to conjugate them, of course.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you posted looks like you want to say, "Lictor of Holy Matters" or "Lictor for Holy Matters," which would be:

> *Lictor Rērum Sanctārum* or *Lictor Rēbus Sanctis*

However, based on your comment you were thinking something to the tune of "Order of Vatican Intelligence Operatives," which presents a quandary, seeing as, per the Wikipedia pages, it would depend on which branch of Vatican government would govern this body. It turns out that, military and civilian offices are under different bodies altogether, namely Vatican City State and Holy See are two different bodies that represent the same areas but hold different function, though both are run by the Pope. In this case, the Vatican City State handles civil matters like the police, while the Holy See runs international and military matters.

So, it would depend on what type of intelligence agency this would be.

If it is civil, then it would be something like:

> *Ordō [Lictorum] Intelligentiae (Rērum Secretārum) prō Statō Civitate Vaticanae* Order [of the Magistrates (Lictors)] of Intelligence for the Vatican City State

and someone in it would be:

> *Lictor Intelligentiae (Rērum Secretārum) prō Statō Civitate Vaticanae* Magistrate (Lictor) of Intelligence for the Vatican City State

However, of it is a military order, then it would be something like:

> *Pontificium Ordō [Lictorum] Intelligentiae (Rērum Secretārum) [pro Sanctā Sedī]* Papal Order [of Magistrates (Lictors)] of Intelligence [for the Holy See]

and someone in it would be:

> *Pontificius Lictor Intelligentiae (Rērum Secretārum) [prō Sanctā Sedī]* Pontifical Magistrate (Lictor) of Intelligence [for the Holy See]

Again, words written in brackets are optional and words in parentheses are alternates. I hope his gives you a starting point. Interestingly, though, it appears that the Holy See is a member of Interpol, so you might want to try it from that angle.

Comment: In this case you would decline the main noun which would be *Ordo* or *Lictor* depending on to what or whom you are referring. The former when referring to the order as a whole, and Lictor when referring to the operative.